# How can I properly show html tags which is come from mysql database using php?

Tags: php, html

Well, In Mysql Database where a table column contain following text :

**Column Text :**

```
&lt;ol&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://web-kreation.com/&quot;&gt;Web-Kreation&lt;/a&gt; for helping out with graphics on the site&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/&quot;&gt;famfamfam.com&lt;/a&gt; (Mark James) Silk Icon's used by NicEdit theme&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Matthias Miller, Dean Edwards and John Resig work on onDOMReady function used in the library&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #808000; background-color: #ffff00;&quot;&gt;&lt;a style=&quot;color: #808000; background-color: #ffff00;&quot; href=&quot;http://www.prototypejs.org/&quot;&gt;Prototype&lt;/a&gt; (Sam Stephenson) for inspriation for several library functions&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ol&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;tinyMCE, FCKEditor&lt;a class=&quot;example1&quot; title=&quot;My ayhoo main&quot; href=&quot;http://www.yahoo.com&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;Yahoo&lt;/a&gt; both great editors used for ideas&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;../libs/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-innocent.gif&quot; alt=&quot;innocent&quot; /&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I want to show it properly to to the browser. So that I am using following php code:

```
$author =  $_SESSION['username'];
$query =  mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE author = '$author' ");
while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

$blog_description = $row['blog_description'];
$blog_description =  nl2br($blog_description);

echo $blog_description;
}
```

But it's showing following text format instead of bold, color, list item etc :

```
<ol>
<li><a href="http://web-kreation.com/">Web-Kreation</a> for helping out with graphics on the site</li>
<li></li>
<li><a href="http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/">famfamfam.com</a> (Mark James) Silk Icon's used by NicEdit theme</li>
<li></li>
<li>Matthias Miller, Dean Edwards and John Resig work on onDOMReady function used in the library</li>
<li></li>
<li><span style="color: #808000; background-color: #ffff00;"><a style="color: #808000; background-color: #ffff00;" href="http://www.prototypejs.org/">Prototype</a> (Sam Stephenson) for inspriation for several library functions</span></li>
</ol>
<p><strong>tinyMCE, FCKEditor<a class="example1" title="My ayhoo main" href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo</a> both great editors used for ideas</strong></p>
<p><strong><img src="../libs/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-innocent.gif" alt="innocent" /></strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

The text is insert to db using this method :

```
function validate($str){
    global $connect;
    $str =  trim($str);
    $str =  stripslashes($str);
    $str =  htmlspecialchars($str);
    $str =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **htmlspecialchars_decode()** or **html_entity_decode()** function

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($blog_description);
```

or

```
  echo html_entity_decode($blog_description);
```

Comment: WOW! Exactly what I want!! Thanks dude  :)